# SHA512 in C # and Java are different

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, sha512

There is such code on C # and java, sha512 in them differs, whether it is possible to make somehow that the result sha512 was identical? I understand the problem in BaseConverter, analog Base64 in Java? Tried

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(str);
```

But I get an error because of getEncoder(). Do I need a library for this?

Code in C#:

```
public string Hash(string str)
{
      string resultStr = String.Empty;
      byte[] data = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(str);
      byte[] result;

      SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
      result = shaM.ComputeHash(data);
      resultStr = ReverseString(BitConverter.ToString(result).ToLower().Replace("-", String.Empty));

      return resultStr.Substring(5, 25);
}       

public static string ReverseString(string s)
{
      char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
      Array.Reverse(charArray);
      return new string(charArray);
}
```

Code in Java:

```
public String Hash(String str) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        digest.update(str.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        result = hexString.toString().toLowerCase();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ReverseString(result).substring(5, 25);
}

 public static String ReverseString(String s)
    {
        return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
    }
```

Comment: I do not know exact anwer but those segments of code looks fishy:
new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(str); and digest.update(str.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
It looks like your conversions have diffrent codings.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: @Vanna: A string isn't UTF8 or Unicode in Java or C# - it's a sequence of UTF-16 code units in both languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're hashing different data - in Java you're converting the string to UTF-16:

```
digest.update(str.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
```

In C# you're using UTF-8:

```
byte[] data = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(str);
```

(I'm not sure why you're creating a new `UTF8Encoding` rather than using `Encoding.UTF8`, admittedly.)

With different input, you *will* get different hashes.

In general, the way to diagnose problems like this is to compare the data at every step of the transformation, whether that's through logging or debugging. In this case you have four transformations:

- Message string to message bytes
- Message bytes to hash bytes
- Hash bytes to hash string (hex)
- Reversed hash string (hex)

Next time, check the output of each step, and you'll work out where the problem is.

(It's not obvious *why* you'd want to reverse the hex output anyway, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the input line for hashing (the string was the salt without the rest of the data, the rest of the data was empty because there was an error in the definition of EditText (EditText returned an empty string) and also fixed the encoding in Java for UTF-8.